# Can I use has_many through: without destroying all associated records on delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I'm trying to make a list of `commissions` to add to applicant_commissions.

```
ApplicantCommission.rb
  belongs_to :applicant
  belongs_to :commission

Applicant.rb

  has_many :applicant_commissions

Commission.rb

  has_many :applicant_commissions
```

The problem is, if I use has_many through: when I delete an Applicant, the Commission is removed too. (and visa versa)

Any suggestions how I can create and destroy this without losing the associated record?

Comment: There is no `has_many :through` anywhere in your question

Comment: I do this all the time and never lose the associated record.  The only thing that should be removed when you remove an Applicant (or a commission) is the association record (ApplicantCommission)

Comment: I'm removing them using rails_admin. Perhaps it's a problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have following relations in your file

ApplicantCommission.rb

```
belongs_to :applicant
belongs_to :commission
```

Applicant.rb

```
has_many :applicant_commissions,  dependent: :destroy
has_many :commissions, through: :applicant_commissions
```

Commission.rb

```
has_many :applicant_commissions,  dependent: :destroy
has_many :applications, through: :applicant_commissions
```

This way your assosiation will not be deleted.
Secondly i would recommend you to have a look at this 'mark_for_destruction' for deletion.
This will help you deleting things easily.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html